# Python API: Tweet with media without file

Tags: python, image, twitter

I'm using twitter from `python` in an environment where I can't store files.

I get a HTTP POST with a text and an image and want to create a tweet from this data without writing a local file (it's `zappa` on AWS api environment).

Tweepy only allows filenames, which does not work for me.

`python-twitter` seems to have something like that, but I can't find a doc for this.

Should I just send POST requests to twitter for uploading the images? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: How are you receiving the images? And if can't you make permanent writes, find a way to either push it online by serializing it, that is, if you cannot find the doc.

Comment: I get it as HTTP Post in base64, so very perfect to send to Twitter, but tweepy wants to make it simple and only allows a filename.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) to [tweepy's API.update_with_media](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.update_with_media) as `file`.

> filename – The filename of the image to upload. **This will automatically be opened unless file is specified**

...

> file – A **file object**, which will be **used instead of opening filename**. **filename is still required, for MIME type detection and to use as a form field in the POST data**

Edit: 
It looks like you have the image data base64 encoded. You can use [base64.b64decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) to decode it before creating the io.BytesIO:

```
file = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_data))
```

Comment: Ah, on the third check I found out that I do get `multipart-formdata`, only the example looked like some encoded data. So i already get file handles.